# Customized Audio Skin in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash, audio

I'm new to HTML. I used the following code for a default skin

```
<embed src="***.mp3" width="400" height="100" autostart="true"></embed>
```

Can any1 please suggest me how to customize the audio skin for my web page.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use jplayer  which allows you customization

http://jplayer.org/latest/demos/